# Perl threads shared two-dimensional array

Tags: multithreading, perl

How to make two-dimensional array shared, so I could change it in thread and I'll see it changed in another thread?
Thank you

```
    our @Cells=(); 
    share(@Cells); 
    for $Row_Of_Cell (0..$Number_Of_Rows-1) { 
            $Cells[$Row_Of_Cell]=&share([]); 
            for $Column_Of_Cell (0..$Number_Of_Columns-1) {
                    $Cells[$Row_Of_Cell][$Column_Of_Cell]=0; 
            } 
    }
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to share the inner structures as well, using `share` or `shared_clone`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my @ar2d : shared;
my @second : shared = qw/A B C D/;
@ar2d = ( shared_clone([qw/a b c d/]),
          \@second,
        );

my $thread = sub {
    my $idx = shift;
    while ('c' eq lc $ar2d[$idx][2]) {
        print "In thread1 $ar2d[$idx][2]\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
};


my $thread1 = threads->create($thread, 0);
my $thread2 = threads->create($thread, 1);

for (1 .. 5) {
    sleep 1;
    print "In main $ar2d[0][2] $ar2d[1][2]\n";
}
$ar2d[0][2] = 'x';
$ar2d[1] = shared_clone([qw/A B X D/]);
print "In main $ar2d[0][2] $ar2d[1][2]\n";

$thread1->join;
$thread2->join;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a 2d array in Perl. Array can only contain scalars. This includes references, so 2d arrays are approximated using arrays of references to arrays. You need to make each of those arrays shared (using `share`), not just the base one.

Note that this kind of sharing is usually indicative of a poor (inefficient and error-prone) design. A worker model is highly recommended when possible.

Comment: Thank you, but how to share those arrays?